# My Angular app is blank on gh-pages, can't load js from travis

Tags: angular, github, travis-ci, github-pages

I uploaded an app I built with Angular, Travis upload it on Github pages with the gh-pages branch but this time all I get is a blank page and the following error messages in the console :

```
Échec du chargement pour l’élément dont la source est « https://hdz.github.io/runtime.js ». [FCS-Training:14:1]
Échec du chargement pour l’élément dont la source est « https://hdz.github.io/polyfills.js ». [FCS-Training:14:1]
Échec du chargement pour l’élément dont la source est « https://hdz.github.io/styles.js ». [FCS-Training:14:1]
Échec du chargement pour l’élément dont la source est « https://hdz.github.io/vendor.js ». [FCS-Training:14:1]
Échec du chargement pour l’élément dont la source est « https://hdz.github.io/main.js ». [FCS-Training:14:1]
```

he doesn’t seem to load the whole js that it’s been deployed by Travis CI.
https://hdz.github.io/FCS-Training/ here is the supposed github pages,
the repository is here https://github.com/Hdz/FCS-Training

I can’t see what I’m doing wrong ? Works like a charm in local:

```
Date: 2020-07-18T10:08:54.367Z - Hash: e5b89a7c4ac0441d6496
4 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 88.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
Time: 311ms
```

I used to deploy like this and it worked but there might has been changes or I did some mistakes ? Travis build is also passing.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the build script in your `package.json` to :

```
"ng build --base-href ./ "
```

The reason it's not working in your repository is that the angular CLI by default use base href="/" in the index.html, consequently the browser can't locate the missing resources.

YOu can find more information about this in [doc](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages)

Comment: It worked ! Thanks a lot ! I have one more question though, my pictures doesn't seem to be uploaded Is it because I didn't put the folder in my assets ?

Comment: No that problem is from your code. Consider using ./assets/images/logo.png

Comment: Also consider marking this question as answered to close the post.

Comment: Hey I'm so sorry to disturb once again, I did transform all the link I had in ./assets/images/logo.png (for instance), it still works in local but it doesn't fix the problem on the gh-pages

Comment: It works fine in your demo https://hdz.github.io/FCS-Training/home

Comment: Rather strange, You're right it works perfectly on Chrome or Edge, but my firefox doesn't like it. I even got a 404 github pages when I click on the /home and still don't have the pictures on it. Thanks anyway I really appreciate it

Comment: It seems you're facing another issue. Can you open another question about it ?